# CSS Span element's border not full height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a separator line for my star rating bar. I'm having trouble getting the separator border-left to go full height. Am I missing something?

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/fusor/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a height to the .answer class, that should fix the issue.

```
.answer {
  width: 135px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(200, 200, 200);
  background: rgb(229, 229, 229);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was missing the height property from my .answer container. Changing that to match the .rating-star fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `.rating{display:block}`

See this example [labs.codeteam.in/lab/!C36Si!pX7i9Lp5cFplpjCSiaBWBcXNv](http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/!C36Si!pX7i9Lp5cFplpjCSiaBWBcXNv)